# How can I collate values from a hashtable and turn them into percentages?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

In PowerShell, I am generating hashtables where the value of a key is an integer, but this needs to be converted into a percentage with respect to the other key-value pairs. Consider the following hashtable:

[image]

There are a total of 4 key-value pairs here. However, only `QuestionSet1ARL` has a value of something other than 0. I therefore want to report that `QuestionSet1ARL` has a value of 100%. Below is a slightly different example:

[image]

Here, both `QuestionSetTrust` and `QuestionSet4` have values of 5. They therefore makeup 50% of the values in the hashtable. If the value of `QuestionSetTrust` was 2 and `QuestionSet4` was 1, the percentages would be 66% and 33% respectively.

I think Ill need to create a secondary hashtable `(enabledSurveys)` to do this (one that only contains the key-value pairs where the value was greater than 0. To do this, I have written a simple loop:

```
foreach ($survey in $initialSurveys.Keys) { 
        # Set the ratio variable equal to the value from the hashtable. For ease of reading.
        $surveyRatio = $initialSurveys.$survey
        if ($surveyRatio -gt 0) {
            $enabledSurveys.add($survey, $surveyRatio)
        }
    }
```

I think I then need to sum the values to achieve a total, and then derive contributedTotal from each of the keys. Before I continue, is there a more intuitive way to derive this information without the need for a second hashtable?

Optimal outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A total sum of the values is needed in order to determine percentage.

```
$InitialSurveys = @{
    'QuestionSetTrust' = 1
    'QuestionSet4' = 5
}
$Total = 0
foreach ($Key in $InitialSurveys.Keys) {
    $Total += $InitialSurveys[$Key]
}
$ResultHash = @{}
foreach ($Key in $InitialSurveys.Keys) {
    $ResultHash[$Key] = "{0}%" -f "$([math]::Round(($InitialSurveys[$Key] / $Total * 100.0), 2))"
}
$ResultHash
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementing [lit's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71106188/7571258), this is a slightly different approach, using the [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) command to calculate the total sum and using hashtable's [`.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.getenumerator) method to iterate over its key/value pairs.

```
$InitialSurveys = @{
    QuestionSetTrust = 2
    QuestionSet4 = 1
}

$Total = ($InitialSurveys.GetEnumerator() | Measure-Object Value -Sum).Sum

$Result = @{}
$InitialSurveys.GetEnumerator().ForEach{
    $Result[ $_.Key ] = $_.Value * 100 / $Total
}

$Result | Format-Table Key, @{ n='Value'; e={ '{0}%' -f ([math]::Round($_.Value)) } }
```

For calculating percentage values the [intrinsic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members#foreach-and-where) `.ForEach{}` is used instead of `ForEach-Object` or `foreach`. It is supposed to be faster than `ForEach-Object` and it more succinct than `foreach( $item in $collection )`.

Finally we use [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)'s ability to provide a custom format by defining a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) for the `Value` column to do rounding and add the `%` sign to the output. This way we keep the exact numeric value in the `$Result` hashtable for possible further calculations and less memory usage.

**Output:**

```text
Name                           Value
----                           -----
QuestionSet4                   33%  
QuestionSetTrust               67%
```

Comment: Thanks for the `GetEnumerator()` example. I was wondering if there was some kind of `lambda` that would do this. I prefer your result of numeric value answers, but it appeared that the OP wanted a `%` on the result. That made the resulting value a string.

Comment: @lit Thanks for the hint. We can keep the numeric result and do the rounding and adding of `%` only for display purposes. See updated answer.